# WinRT Unit Test Library project timeout SocketException

Tags: unit-testing, windows-runtime, fiddler, windows-store

I wish to use Fiddler to capture HTTP traffic between a WinRT Unit Test Library client app and an OData web api Asp.net Mvc 4 server.

Using Visual Studio 2013 I have created a **Unit Test Library project** for a WinRT Windows Store App (Windows 8.1).

I have set my service api url to http://localhost.fiddler:, Fiddler is running and capturing Non-Browser traffic.

When I run a simple test it fails with: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: *A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 127.0.0.1:8888*

I know that 127.0.0.1:8888 is the default Fiddler proxy address.

I assumed that the problem was caused by Windows 8 blocking apps sending network traffic to the local computer and ran the **Fiddler AppContainer Loopback Exemption Utility** to enable the Unit Test Library to send network traffic to 127.0.0.1:8888

I cannot find an app with the Package display name or the Package name (AC Name) set in the Unit Test Library project Package.appmanifest file.

Why does this project not appear in the AppContainer Loopback Exemption Utility?

Answer (score 2):

The Unit Test Library WinRT app does not appear in the Fiddler AppContainer Loopback Exemption Utility **unless the app is running**.

Set a breakpoint in a [TestMethod] in a Unit Test Library [TestClass] and run the [TestMethod] in Debug mode.  When the test breaks run the Fiddler AppContainer Loopback Exemption Utility.  The Unit Test Library application should now appear in the listed Win8 apps.  Note: The "Display Name" will be the name assigned in the Package.appmanifest and the Package Name (AC Name) will be the Guid assigned in the Package.appmanifest.

Enable Loopback Exemption for the app.  This only has to be done once.  The loopback exemption is remembered although the app is temporary.

Note: If you run the Fiddler AppContainer Loopback Exemption Utility when the Unit Test Library WinRT app is not running you will get an warning dialog saying: *A Loopback exemption exists for SID: s-X-XX-X-XXXXXXXX....
no AppContainer with that SID could be found.*